Error al realizar una solicitud a ASP.NET Core Web Api 6-7-8 desde flutter
Hola tengo un problema al intentar consumir el api .net 8 en flutter
este es mi consumo en flutter con el paquete http de flutter
Este funciona es una api con nestjs
var response3 = await http.get(
          Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.53:3000/api/products?limit=10&offset=0"));
      print('Response status: ${response3.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response3.body}');

El problema es este que no funciona de ninguna de estas formas ejecuto mi api aspnet core 8 con http o https
- var response2 = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "https://localhost:7190/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
      print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "https://192.168.1.53:7190/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "https://10.0.2.2:7190/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

tampoco funciona con
    - var response2 = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "http://localhost:5044/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
      print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://192.168.1.53:5044/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://10.0.2.2:5044/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

decir que https://localhost:7091 http://localhost:5044 si funcionan en postman
En todo caso despliego la asp.net core api web 8 con IIS Express
y tampoco funciona (cabe aclarar en FLUTTER, porque en postman si funciona https://localhost:44307 y http://localhost:46007)
  - var response2 = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "http://localhost:44307/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
      print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://192.168.1.53:44307/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://10.0.2.2:44307/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

y tambien
- var response2 = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "http://localhost:46007/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
      print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://192.168.1.53:46007/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

- var response2 = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                  "http://10.0.2.2:46007/api/Factura/facturas-por-caja/3102DF73-D6A4-4AD3-0AE0-08DC7074A1CE"));
          print('Response status: ${response2.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response2.body}');

es que no encuentra la url asi el api este desplegada en http o https o iisexpress , lo intente consumir con http o https  y con siglas como "localhost:7190" "localhost:5044" y funciona en postman pero no en flutter ,con http y https intente con  "MY_IP_DIRECCION:7190" "MY_IP_DIRECCION:5044" no funciona ni en postman ni en flutter y tambien con "10.0.2.2:7190" "10.0.2.2:5044"  y tampoco funciona ,de igual forma con iisexpress "localhost:44307","MY_IP_DIRECCION:44307","10.0.2.2:44307" y tengo todo no logro entender ,my project in guthub https://github.com/apoj2/jwt-auth-net-8,  algo para agregar es que tengo un api en nestjs dockerizada en el puerto 3000 y funciona, la pruebo sin dockerizar y funciona, pero esta api en .net no, cuando lo debugueo en flutter del try me brinca directamente al return y luego me tira la siguiente excepción

"The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was
called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer."

este error eso si me lo da cuando lo corro en el emulador web, cuando lo corro en un emulador virtual o en mi dispositivo físico, dura bastante tiempo y el error es el siguiente

"DioException (DioException [connection timeout]: The request
connection took longer than 0:00:00.000000. It was aborted. Error:
SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out,
errno = 110), address = 192.168....ip, port = 4...)".

He buscado por Internet y me dice que puede ser con los CORS en el caso de que lo corra en el emulador web, y en el caso de los emuladores virtuales y físicos he encontrado que puede ser con la red, lo raro es que desde postman no me da problemas, no se ha que se deba, o si a alguien le ha pasado similar, es como si el api si desplegara localmente(localhost) pero no desplegara en el pc(192.168....IP) que hago para desplegarla en el pc
este es mi program:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });


//DB

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("local");
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});


//DEPENDECY INJECTION
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogService, LogService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericoService<>), typeof(GenericoService<>));

//ADD IDENTITY

builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//CONFIG IDENTITY

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;

    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

// ADD AUTHENTICATION SHEMA AND JWTBEARER

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
        };
    });



// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
//{
//    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",new OpenApiSecurityScheme
//    {
//                Name = "Bearer",
//                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
//                Description = "Please your enter token with this format 'Bearer YOUR_TOKEN'",
//                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
//                BearerFormat = "JWT",
//                Scheme = "bearer"
//    });
//    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
//    {
//        {
//            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
//            {
//                Name = "Bearer",
//                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
//                Reference =
//                {
//                    Id = "Bearer",
//                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
//                } 
//            },
//            new List<string>()
//        }
//    });
//});
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//ADD CORS
app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyOrigin();
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//ADD AUTHENTICATION
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Este es mi launchsettings
 {
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5044"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7190;http://localhost:5044"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:46007",
      "sslPort": 44307
    }
  }
}


Aca estas mostrando tu program.cs que no nos dice absolutamente nada de tu problema.. cuando le das play a tu api, esta abre un navegador, que por defecto te muestra el puerto y la url donde se va a ejecutar.. para encontrar los endpoints, podes agregar swagger a esa url y vas a ver la inforamcion brindada por swagger.. todo lo que pusiste en la pregunta, no da idea de cual pueda ser el problema...

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Yo de Flutter ni idea, pero tiene mucho sentido que desde algo web te de problemas de CORS y desde un emulador te de problemas de red, ya que quizás tiene alguna interfaz virtual. Te recomiendo habilitar CORS en tu API para que validar/descartar ese problema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Además, te comento que Postman no te sirve para comprobar problemas con cors. Si tienes Edge o Chrome, abres las pestañas de desarrollador (F2) y buscas la pestaña "Consola de Red", presionas "Create a request" y pones la url. De haber error te lo mostrará en la consola (la consola normal), en caso contrario se mostrará en la respuesta.

los cors los tengo, ya que lo pruebo con angular o react y si accedo a la direccion https://localhost:7190/api/factura/......... si me funciona, lo que no se es como "globalizar" mi aplicacion a nivel de red o computadora, concordamos con que localhost si existe , ahora como pongo mi aplicacion a nivel de ip de mi ordenador 192.148.2.0 ? ,voy arevisar con el metodo de consola de red

(NO ES LA SOLUCION RECOMENDADA PERO SI UNA OPCION)
Tambien es (recomendable) ver a https://andrewlock.net/8-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/ para una respuesta mas detallada.
Para los que vean esta respuesta para poder acceder desde flutter a un api en asp.net core 6-7-8 es necesario

Buscar nuestra ip:
windows : ipconfig
linux:ifconfig
si estas con wifi escoge la (ipv4) de la opcion "Adaptador lan inalambrica", si no funciona o no aparece consulta en internet como obtener tu ip mas detalladamente


DIRECCION_IP = ipv4   ej(191.168.4.23)
PUERTO_ABIERTO = 5000
colocar en el program :
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000","http://191.168.4.23:5000");
Recordar dar ctr + s en el program que al momento de levantar el servidor con (dotnet run) no se autoguarda.
Como lo corremos?
abrimos la terminal y buscamos el archivo de nuestro api "nombre_api.csproj" con el comando de terminal (ls) miramos si esta el archivo por terminal, sino con (cd) buscamos donde esta el archivo y  vamos a la carpeta donde se encuentra este y corremos el comando (dotnet run) , ahi en la terminal veremos que los servidores que se expone es "http://localhost:5000" y "http://191.168.4.23:5000" o el que pongan teniendo en cuenta la direccion ip de nuestra maquina y el puerto,  ya podremos acceder mediante postman y mediante nuestro emulador , para detener le damos al boton rojo de detener ejecucuion de comandos o dependiendo en donde estemos ctrl + c , recuerda siempre cerrarlo aunque al cerrar los programas estan configurados para cerrar todos los puertos abiertos por seccion
En conclusion
ASP.NET CORE
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000","http://191.168.4.23:5000");

BLAZOR
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel() // Use Kestrel as the web server
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // Set the content root directory
  .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "http://191.168.4.23:5000") // Bind to two URLs
  .UseIISIntegration() // Enable IIS integration (if applicable)
  .UseStartup<Startup>() // Use the Startup class for configuration (corrected typo)
  .Build();

las dos formas estan bien en .net8 simplemente con un efoque diferente de proyecto ya que uno es un asp.net core api web y la otra es para app web blazor
Porque correrlo con (dotnet run) y no con (http) - (https) -(iis express)?
con (http) - (https) - (iis express)
Estos son servidores ligeros para desarrollo local web ,osea con esto tenemos lo principal para simular un servidor y correrlo para nosotros ver los datos
con (dotnet run)
Ya es muy diferente ya que esto si es un servidor web no una simulacion como los otros por lo tanto si podremos acceder mediante red a nuestra api
En definicion de dotnet-dotnet run es un comando de la CLI de .NET que inicia una aplicación ASP.NET Core directamente desde el código fuente.
-Cuando usas dotnet run, la aplicación se ejecuta utilizando Kestrel, que es un servidor web de propósito general y multiplataforma que está integrado en ASP.NET Core.
-Kestrel es un servidor web muy eficiente y adecuado para escenarios de producción, pero puede requerir configuraciones adicionales para tareas específicas como la terminación de SSL y la administración de múltiples sitios.
-Con dotnet run, puedes ejecutar y depurar tu aplicación directamente desde la línea de comandos sin necesidad de IDEs específicos como Visual Studio.
Estás ejecutando tu aplicación directamente en el servidor Kestrel, que es un servidor web integrado en ASP.NET Core. Kestrel es un servidor web de propósito general y multiplataforma diseñado para ser eficiente y escalable. Aunque Kestrel es adecuado para el desarrollo local, también se puede configurar para su uso en entornos de producción. dotnet run es una forma rápida y conveniente de ejecutar tu aplicación ASP.NET Core directamente desde el código fuente, sin necesidad de una infrastructura de servidor web completa como IIS (Internet Information Services)(Diferente a IIS Express que es lo mismo pero "Express" osea con lo basico para simular)

No entendi nada de tu respuesta.. ahi le estas diciendo como levantar los puertos por codigo, cuando alcanza con modificar el json de configuracion para pasarle los puertos.. si no, cuando vaya a produccion, van a quedar ahi clavados...

no recomiendo mi solucion para produccion en el momento...., solo lo recomiendo para probar en local y para las personas que no concreteen el desplegarlo de otra manera y sea su unica solucion, cuando pase a produccion y se me de ese problema en especifico, busco y rectifico de igual manera mi respuesta para dar una solucion a otros desarrolladores que les ocurra lo mismo, ojo ACLARO esta solucion no es para produccion solo para probar asp.net core api web en un servidor de red local y poder probar la aplicacion flutter en el emulador de android studio

La respuesta esta un poco mas enfocada a resolver mi pregunta y un problema especifico, no el problema completo como tal:(, si puedes Apoyarla con temas de produccion y eso puedes aclaralo en otro comentario,porque yo si me quedo corto en eso

Es que estas matando moscas con cañones aca. No necesitas configurar kestrel, desde dentro de tu app... porque estas haciendo eso? no me queda claro porque kestrel soluciona tu problema (cuando nunca dijiste de que forma ejecutabas, y kestrel es la ejecucion por defecto desde hace mil versiones).. es mas.. kestrel antes era iis express ;)... kestrel es la evolucion.. o sea.. porque tenes que reconfigurar kestrel ,y no dejar los parametros por defecto para que funcione flutter? si es un entorno como cualquier otro?

para mi, estas sobredimensionando tu problema.. probesta con la api por defecto de c#??? y le pegaste desde flutter sin hacer mas?? si solo da problemas de cors, ese es tu unico problema..

en produccion vas a usar kestrel tambien.. y vas a encontrar el mismo problema, salvo que hagas un deploy en k8 con un ingress.. si no, el mismo problema... si dockerizas y pones un servidor nginx intermedio lo podrias arreglar.. entiendo que esta sobreoptimizacion arregla tu problema en desa.. pero es impracticable en otro entorno y vas a volver al problema original...

mmm no me entiendes o no comprendiste , no del todo pero si , explico DETALLADAMENTE mi problema , con respeto no entiendo que no quedo claro, que aunque lanze el proyecto con http o https o iisexpress no funciona en flutter porque de una u otra manera al lanzar estos servidores solo son LOCALES yo los necesito a nivel de red para con mi emulador poder acceder a ellos ,no entiendo ni yo el problema y estoy en busca de una mejor solucion ,pero hasta el momento la unica forma es configurar una url con la ip de mi dispositivo y compilar con (dotnet run), porque no funciona con los otros servers..

no estoy seguro porque no funciona con los otros servers pero supongo es eso http,https y iisexpress son solo locales para lanzarlos a nivel de red toca hacer otra maraña y por el momento la unica es lanzar el aplicativo con dotnet run y no por los otros servers
